nginx forwarding issue to keycloak
Nginx Unable to Proxy Keycloak on Port 8080 - Connection Refused
Environment Details

Keycloak: 24.0.0
Nginx: 1.27.3

Problem Description
I'm experiencing an issue where Nginx can successfully proxy the backend on port 8081, but fails to proxy Keycloak running on port 8080.
Detailed Observations
Keycloak Endpoint (:8080)
curl -I https://xxxx.de/auth/
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.27.3
Date: Sat, 07 Dec 2024 11:12:46 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive

Backend Endpoint (:8081)
bashCopycurl -I https://xxxx.de/api/
HTTP/1.1 401
Server: nginx/1.27.3
Date: Sat, 07 Dec 2024 11:16:23 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
# ... other headers

This is correct because of JWT and authorization.
Nginx Error Log
Copy2024/12/07 12:12:30 [error] 1818792#1818792: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 194.92.121.85, server: www.xxxx.de, request: "HEAD /auth/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/auth/", host: "xxxx.de"
... similar errors repeated
Current Configuration
Podman Compose File
yamlCopyversion: '3.9'

services:
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.0
    container_name: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=123123
      - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
      - KC_PROXY_HEADERS=forwarded
    command: ["start-dev"]
... other services

Nginx Configuration
location /auth/ {
    add_header X-Debug-Referer $http_referer;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}

podman ps
2f314807665f  quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:24.0.0                     start-dev             56 minutes ago  Up 56 minutes            0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp    keycloak

Questions
Why is Nginx unable to connect to the Keycloak container on port 8080?
What could be causing the connection refused error?
Are there any specific configuration steps I'm missing?
I've verified that:
Keycloak container is running
Port 8080 is exposed in the Podman compose file
Nginx configuration appears correct
